# Cannot exit cmd text typing?

Tags: c, cmd

After running this program on C, I cannot exit from it through cmd no matter how many times I press Ctrl + Z. This program counts the number of tabs, new lines and new blanks

```
main()
{
  int c, nl, nb, nt;

  nl = 0;
  nb = 0;
  nt = 0;
  while ((c == getchar()) != EOF){ 
      if (c == '\n')
        ++nl;
      if (c == '\t')
        ++nt;
      if (c == ' ')
        ++nb; 
      }   
  printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nt, nb);

}
```

Pressing Ctrl + C only exits from it.

Comment: Yes, as I said, it exits from it but how will it count the tabs, new lines, etc?

Comment: What operating system are you using? `Ctrl + Z` is not `EOF` on all systems. On UNIX and Mac OS X you could try `Ctrl + D`.

Comment: remove == in c== getchar(). it should be =

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ctl+D` is `EOF` in `UNIX based systems`.you need to press ctl+D when ever you want to stop

`Ctl+Z` is `EOF` in `Windows`.you need to press ctl+z when ever you want to stop.

```
while ((c == getchar()) != EOF) ==> while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)   
          ^^                                  ^
```

Comment: Ctrl-d is EOF in Unix (not gcc) ctrl-z is EOF in DOS/Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Windows, the situation is that you basically have to do the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> at the beginning of a line -- i.e., you have to have hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, then do the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, then (depending on how the input is being read) possibly <kbd>enter</kbd> again.

You can also use <kbd>F6</kbd> to signal the end of the input. At least in most cases, this will work even when/if it does *not* immediately follow an <kbd>enter</kbd>.